# Disabling Animation For Angular UI Bootstrap Modals Completely

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap Modal component, and I can disable animation for a modal like this:

`var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: false,
    component: 'myComponent'
});`

Is there any way to disable animation completely on all modals in my application without css addition/modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*$uibModal* object has a provider named *$uibModalProvider*, and it is possible to use it in configuration phase to set default values for *$uibModal*.

Something like this will work:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .config(['$uibModalProvider', function ($uibModalProvider) {
        $uibModalProvider.options.animation = false;
    }]);
```

It is also possible to provide default values for other options all at once as well:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .config(['$uibModalProvider', function ($uibModalProvider) {
        $uibModalProvider.options = {
            animation: false,
            backdrop: false,
            keyboard: false
        };
    }]);
```